# Gradle fails with OutOfMemoryError during lintVital

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, lint

I created a specific build type for our project, which disables R8 for release builds in order to skip minification, obfuscation, etc. during CI builds for merge requests. Unfortunately since then the build started failing. It gets stuck at `:app:lintVital...` every time and then it fails with `OutOfMemoryError`. There is no such problem if I revert my changes. The configuration has 4gb of heap space and the machine it's running on has 16gb of ram. Am I missing something?

Here are the build types:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-no-logs.pro'
}

releaseNoR8 {
    shrinkResources false
    minifyEnabled false
    matchingFallbacks = ['release']
}
```